# Health Check Redis in net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, redis

I ran into a problem, implemented distributed query caching through Redis, through an intermediate handler, everything works. But having a question about the availability of the Redis service, if it is unavailable, my application crashes with a "No connection" error,
I want to implement a check for connection to Redis, and after that if the connection is not successfully tried again after n seconds, but incoming requests should bypass caching until the Redis service is available.

I understand in microservices there should be such an implementation?
Tell me through what it can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Does Polly suit your use case? https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: Yes, Polly suits me, but I saw the implementation only through http requests.  is it possible to configure it for a service type with a custom type?

Comment: Yea it's possible.

Comment: Yes, thanks, after searching, I found this post: https://medium.com/@therealjordanlee/retry-circuit-breaker-patterns-in-c-with-polly-9aa24c5fe23a I will use it as an example